# How to remove PHP Code Sniffer's highlighting from the code editor window in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, phpcodesniffer

I've started using PHP Code Sniffer (phpcs) with Netbeans. Phpcs is managed by PHPCSMD plugin. It's configuration is found in Tools > Options > PHP > 'Debugging' and 'PHPCSMD' tabs.

I really want to stop phpcs to mark warnings and notices in the code editor's window. At the moment, all messages from phpcs are shown in the debug window below the code editor (and this is good) as well as in the code editor as shown in the picture:

[image]

How can I turn in-code highlighting for phpcs messages?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will help somebody:

Tools >> untick 'Show phpcsmd annoatations'